# Bootstrap Modal Refering to an input fields value (Not Working)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

Anyone that could provide any help to this issue i'd greatly appreciated it, thank you in advance.

Below is my code for my bootstrap modal. On click of the submit button I am trying to refer to the input field within the modal to retrive its value/user input.

As you can see i have attempted using  `document.getElementById(blogbox).innerHTML`.

This is non-functional so I may be barking up the wrong tree so any guidance to pulling that data in once again is appreciated.

```
<div class='modal fade' id=addblog tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>Add Blog</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <form name='testForm'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='message-text' class='control-label'>Blog Name:</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='blogbox'>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick=addblog('5','" + "document.getElementById(blogbox).innerHTML" + "')>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've tried to simplify your question down for the sake of anyone else coming along... Here is your HTML:

```
<div class='modal fade' id=addblog tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h4 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>Add Blog</h4></div><div class='modal-body'><form name='testForm'><div class='form-group'><label for='message-text' class='control-label'>Blog Name:</label><input type='text' class='form-control' id='blogbox'></div></form></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick=addblog('5','document.getElementById(blogbox).innerHTML')>Add</button></div></div></div></div>
```

Specifically, you are having trouble with your onclick attributes for the HTML buttons. The first thing I notice is that you wrote your selector/actions like this:

```
'document.getElementById(blogbox).innerHTML'
```

The single quotes means that your evaluating this code as a string instead of executing it. We want to instead execute it.

Second, blogbox actually does need to be in a string since it is the HTML element id that we are searching for (see my source on how to properly use the JS getElementById method).

```
document.getElementById('blogbox').innerHTML
```

Finally, innerHTML is not the action you are searching for since it is intended to return HTML inside of a parent element. Instead, try using value.

So in conclusion, if you change your onclick attributes to read:

```
addblog('5', document.getElementById('blogbox').value)
```

then your code should start executing your function as intended.

Source:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: Thank you so much, been stuck on that for a lifetime!